# Is there any way to Remove all Redis Client Connections?

Tags: redis

Is there any way to **Remove all Redis Client Connections** with one command?

I know that it's possible to remove by IP:PORT

```
CLIENT KILL addr:port
```

Also I found that is possible to do this since Redis 2.8.12.
But 
I couldn't find anything about.

Comment: SHUTDOWN :) Seriously though, no. What's the use case?

Comment: This is just for dev purpose, we're getting on the limit of connections and I wanna kill everyone.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`CLIENT KILL` can receive `TYPE` argument that can be one of a three connection types; `normal`, `slave` and `pubsub`.

You can kill all open connections by sending the following three commands:

```
CLIENT KILL TYPE normal
CLIENT KILL TYPE slave
CLIENT KILL TYPE pubsub
```

Note that you can skip the later two if you do not use them (slave and pubsub connections).

You can also add a `SKIPME no` for a kamikaze connections killer.

Comment: This is only available from 2.8.11 though: https://redis.io/commands/client-kill, before that only the `CLIENT KILL addr:port` format is accepted.

Comment: True @guival, but if you still use Redis 2.8 in May 2019, killing all clients in one go should be the least of your problems.

Comment: From doc: ">= 5: Replaced `slave` TYPE with `replica`. `slave` still supported for backward compatibility."

Comment: What if new connections come up after `CLIENT KILL`  is executed? Any way to KILL and STOP more connections from coming up?

Comment: What are you trying to do @piepi? The way to do it is to make a breaking change in ACL (like changing the default user password) before killing everyone.

Answer (score 8):

So `SHUTDOWN` is definitely the easiest way, especially in dev.

However, although Redis doesn't have a `CLIENT KILL *` variant, you can script it. AFAIR you could even do it in Lua but I checked now and `CLIENT LIST` errs so I'm guessing that's changed. Still, it is fairly easy to do this with the CLI - this appears to do the trick:

```
redis-cli CLIENT LIST | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | cut -d = -f 2 | awk -e '{ print "CLIENT KILL " $0 }' | redis-cli -x
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following command to check your connection numbers:

`netstat -an | grep :6379 | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l`

Then try Redis Client command to kill connection:
http://redis.io/commands/client-kill